# How does this code work? They are removing an item in an array based on a condition. The syntax confuses me

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Image of problem

[image]

They lost me at the part where " = -1"

This is my understanding of the solution(so far). 
They took the arr variable and scanned for elements that have a remainder of 1 when divided by 2. The = -1 part is where I'm confused.

- What are the steps going on in here to replace those odd numbers as
  negative 1?
- Could someone explain in more depth how "arr[arr % 2    == 1]"
  works? I think I have a very simple understanding of it.

Also, what is this particular technique called?

EDIT: 
So I tried the solution they gave and it doesn't even run...Not sure if I did something wrong on my end.

Original site link: [Source](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/101-numpy-exercises-python/)

Comment: Check out the Boolean indexing info [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like anything else you're trying to understand, take it step by step.  Try printing out each of these intermediate expressions:

- `arr` is a numpy array.  This is important, because all of these steps depend on special numpy features - they wouldn't work on an ordinary list.
- `arr % 2` is an array of the same size, containing the parity of each of the original numbers - 0 for even, 1 for odd.
- `arr % 2 == 1` turns that into an array of booleans - False for even, True for odd.
- `arr[arr % 2 == 1]` invokes numpy's special boolean indexing feature - it gives you a view of a (possibly discontiguous) subset of the array, wherever the index value was True.  In this case, the view contains only the odd numbers of the original array.
- `arr[arr % 2 == 1] = -1` assigns the same value to each element in the view, overwriting all of the original odd numbers.

A key numpy concept used in all of the steps is "broadcasting" - basically, whenever an operation is attempted between an array and a single element, the single element is effectively replicated to match the size of the array.  So, in `arr % 2`, the `2` notionally becomes an array of `2`s, the same size as `arr`.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the post. I tried running `print(arr[arr % 2 == 1] = -1)` and it gave me an error. Why is that? I ran a print for every bulletpoint you've mentioned but the last one didn't work.

Comment: This is the error given: **SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression**

Comment: The final line I wrote is actually a statement, not an expression (a distinction that is rather more distinct in Python than in most languages).  Its result is the new, final value of `arr`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!